# Derive $\sum i^2$ without knowing the answer first

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Standard proof that $\sum_1^n i^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ is given by induction. It is of course a valid method. However, I find that it requires me to memorize the answer. Is there any way I can sit in an exam and just derive the result from scratch without memorization?

This question is apparently more general and different than [Gaussian proof for the sum of squares?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122546/gaussian-proof-for-the-sum-of-squares)
and I have seen quite a few great answers other than the "Gaussian method" in the post

Comment: You could write $i^2$ in binomial notation as $2\binom i2+2\binom i1$ and use binomial identities...

Comment: One way is to first start by deriving the value of the (telescoping) sum:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (i+1)^3-i^3$$
Then by expanding the summand and by the linearity property, infer the value of $\sum_{i=1}^n i^2$ by using the (well-known) values of $\sum_{i=1}^n i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n 1$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity

Comment: Try guessing that it will be a cubic polynomial and solve for the coefficients.

Comment: This older question is very much in the vein of the present one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2979513/137524

Comment: Some time ago, I proved it by breaking up the summation such that we can use the known formula for $\sum_1^n i$.

Comment: The simpler sums can be written as $$\binom{m+1}{k+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{m}\binom{n}{k}$$ which can be proved combinatorially. Then $n^2=2\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{1},$ so $$\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^{m} n^2 &= 2\binom{m+1}{3}+\binom{m+1}{2}\\&=\frac{(m+1)m(m-1)}{3}+\frac{(m+1)m}{2}\\&=\frac{m(m+1)}{6}\left(2(m-1)+3\right)\\&=\frac{m(m+1)(2m+1)}{6}\end{align}$$

Comment: The reason that $$\binom{m+1}{k+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{m}\binom{n}{k}$$ is that $\binom{m+1}{k+1}$ counts the number of subsets of size $k+1$ of the set $\{0,1,\dots,m\}$ and $\binom{n}{k}$ counts those subsets with maximum element $n.$

Comment: So, for example, we have $$n^3=6\binom{n}{3}+6\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{1}$$ and you get $$\sum_{n=0}^{m} m^3 = 6\binom{n+1}{4}+6\binom{n+1}{3}+\binom{n+1}{2}$$

Comment: Another approach to discover the formula is to use a *difference table*, where the first row contains the first several values of the sequence, starting with $n=0$, and each subsequent row contains the differences of adjacent values in the row above it:
\begin{align}
0 && 1 && 5 && 14 && 30 \\
1 && 4 && 9 && 16 \\
3 && 5 && 7 \\
2 && 2 \\
0 
\end{align}
Now read off the first column as multipliers for binomial coefficients:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = 0 \binom{n}{0}+1 \binom{n}{1}+3 \binom{n}{2}+2 \binom{n}{3}=\frac{n (n + 1) (2 n + 1)}{6}$$

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/sum-of-first-n-squares-equals-fracnn12n16